# Get register stdout_lines and remove the space

Tags: ansible, consul

I am trying to assign an output (variable) value to a file. Also, I would like to remove the space in front of the value. The initial command output is like below.

Command output:

```
# /usr/local/bin/consul acl bootstrap 

AccessorID:       361e72451-3709-074b-ee7c-0a2bbe019db6
SecretID:         9d4f8869-506a-121e-d01d-768495af56756
Description:      Bootstrap Token (Global Management)
Local:            false
Create Time:      2020-09-23 12:48:58.775483049 +0000 UTC
Policies:
   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001 - global-management
```

Code:

```yaml
- name: Consul acl bootstrap
   shell: /usr/local/bin/consul acl bootstrap 
   register: bootstrap

- set_fact:
    secrets_list: "{{ bootstrap.stdout_lines |  map('trim') | list }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ item | regex_search('[^:]*$') }}"
  with_items: "{{ secrets_list[1] }}"
  register: secret_key

- name: append the key
  lineinfile:
    path: /root/.bash_profile
    line: 'export CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN="{{ secret_key.stdout }}"'
```

Here is my desired output

```
export CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN= 9d4f8869-506a-121e-d01d-768495af56756
```

but what I am getting is

```
export CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN="{'results': [{'msg': '         9d4f8869-506a-121e-d01d-768495af56756', 'failed': False, 'changed': False, 'item': 'SecretID:         9d4f8869-506a-121e-d01d-768495af56756, 'ansible_loop_var': 'item'}], 'msg': 'All items completed', 'changed': False}"
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consul 1.7.3 ([CHANGELOG](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#173-may-05-2020)) added a `-format=json` output to all `consul acl` commands. You can simplify this play by rewriting the playbook to use this JSON output.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Bootstrap Consul ACL system
      command: /usr/local/bin/consul acl bootstrap -format=json
      register: bootstrap

    - name: Set bootstrap_secret_id fact
      set_fact:
        bootstrap_secret_id: "{{ (bootstrap.stdout | from_json).SecretID }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "export CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN={{ bootstrap_secret_id }}"
```

```
$ ansible-playbook bootstrap-consul-acl.yaml
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Bootstrap Consul ACL system] *********************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Set bootstrap_secret_id fact] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "export CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN=954ba1c0-581f-80e9-7a1f-ebb29d364ff1"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Even nicer than mine indeed.

Comment: Thank you @Blake. Working nicely!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a regex to do such a simple split operation, especially knowing that Python's [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) work pretty well for those use cases.

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    bootstrap:
      stdout_lines:
        - 'AccessorID:       361e72451-3709-074b-ee7c-0a2bbe019db6'
        - 'SecretID:         9d4f8869-506a-121e-d01d-768495af56756'
        - 'Description:      Bootstrap Token (Global Management)'
        - 'Local:            false'
        - 'Create Time:      2020-09-23 12:48:58.775483049 +0000 UTC'
        - 'Policies:'
        - ' 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001 - global-management'
              
  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: "export CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN={{ bootstrap.stdout_lines[1].split()[1] }}"
```

This yields the result:

```
PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "export CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN=9d4f8869-506a-121e-d01d-768495af56756"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

And to go further, you could [`select`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#select) and [`match`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings) the correct line of your output.

Given the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    bootstrap:
      stdout_lines:
        - 'AccessorID:       361e72451-3709-074b-ee7c-0a2bbe019db6'
        - 'SecretID:         9d4f8869-506a-121e-d01d-768495af56756'
        - 'Description:      Bootstrap Token (Global Management)'
        - 'Local:            false'
        - 'Create Time:      2020-09-23 12:48:58.775483049 +0000 UTC'
        - 'Policies:'
        - ' 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001 - global-management'
              
  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: "export CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN={{ (bootstrap.stdout_lines | select('match','SecretID:') | first).split()[1] }}"
```

Gives the same recap, of course.